# Laravel 5.5 - Show specific category from API response

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am returning an API response inside a Categories controller in Laravel 5.5 like this...

```
public function get(Request $request) {

   $categories = Category::all();

   return Response::json(array(
    'error' => false,
    'categories_data' => $categories,
  ));

}
```

Now I am trying to also have the option to return a specific category, how can I do this as I am already using the get request in this controller?

Do I need to create a new route or can I modify this one to return a specific category only if an ID is supplied, if not then it returns all?

Comment: it would be better if you make another, try to learn resource routing, you will have a clear understanding

Comment: you are not using `$request` in your method then why do you require it?

Answer (score 0):

Better case is to create a new route, but you can also change the current one to retrieve all models if the parameter is not supplied. You first gotta choose which approach you will be using. For splitting it into multiple calls you can see [Resource controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/controllers#resource-controllers) and for using one method you can follow [Optional Route Parameters](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#parameters-optional-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

It will be much cleaner if you will create another route. For example

- /categories --> That you have
- /categories/{id} -> this you need to create

And then add method at same controller

```
public function show($id) {

    $categories = Category::find($id);

    return Response::json(array(
        'error' => false,
        'categories_data' => $categories,
    ));
}
```

But if you still want to do it at one route you can try something like this:

- /categories -> will list all categories
- /categories?id=2 -> will give you category of ID 2

Try this:

```
public function get(Request $request) {

    $id = $request->get('id');
    $categories = $id ? Category::find($id) : Category::all();

    return Response::json(array(
        'error' => false,
        'categories_data' => $categories,
    ));
}
```